# How to reinstall linux-libc-dev:amd64

Tags: package-management

I used `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to repair an incomplete update. It solved at least most of the problems, but says

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-libc-dev:amd64 (--configure): package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it brefore attemping to configure it.
```

I entered `sudo apt-get remove linux-libc-dev:amd64` and it removed some parts of the package and said:

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-libc-dev:amd64 (--remove): package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it brefore attemping a removal
```

How can I reinstall it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling it manually from the `.deb` file (`sudo dpkg -i file.deb`). You can either find it in `/var/cache/apt/archives` or (if your cache has been purged) download it from http://packages.ubuntu.com. Be careful to install the correct version (the same version which is "installed" currently).